# Arinc labels treatment

Tags: c, algorithm

I treat arinc labels. Each 1 second, I receive them (Maybe just some ones).I consider a label as valid when SSM of the corresponding frame is not normal operation for 10 consecutive frame. 
Here is my algorithm, I want know if it is the best way to code it:

Counter is a global data which is initialized with 9.

```
if(Label is received)
{
  if(SSM == NO)
  {
    Get the label and set it as valid
    Counter = 9;
  }
  else
 {
   if(counter > 0)
     {
       counter --;
     }
     else
    {
     label is invalid
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: when the SSI indicates `normal` then that specific instance of the label is usable.  To wait for 10 instances of the label SSI field to continuously be indicating `normal` is to delay by (in your case) 10 seconds, which is 'forever' for a datum that updates once per second.   Much better to use `normal` data immediately and perform validation on the data field, perhaps by debounce filtering or averaging the data or low pass filtering.

Comment: the posted code does not perform as stated in the question.  Rather it `immediately` sets the label status as `valid` and does not set the label status as `invalid` until 10 consecutive instance of a `not normal` label is received.   Also, there are some 256 labels,  but this code does not differentiate between them